# Reference View Members in XAML when DataContext is already Set to View Model

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm wondering why I can't directly reference shared, partial class members from the code behind, in the xaml bindings (without setting the instance of the partial class on the DataContext).

From my reading, I understand that x:Class attribute in the XAML is equivalent to a partial class declaration in the CLR.  This is why it's possible to refer to a XAML node in the code behind, via the node's 'Name' attribute.  Why can't objects that are realised in the partial class in the code behind, be referenced from the XAML?

I realise that I can set a DataContext, but I would prefer to compose the view in the shared partial class (responsible for view content, and behaviour only) and set the view model object on the DataContext, like so:

### mainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="button_binding.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid Margin="0,0,183,134">
        <Button x:Name="button0" Command="{Binding Button0.DelegateClick}" Content="{Binding Button0.Content}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="112,82,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>
        <Button x:Name="button1" Command="{Binding Button1.DelegateClick}" Content="{Binding Button1.Content}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="112,134,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>
        <ToggleButton Name="button2" IsChecked="{Binding Button2.On, Mode=OneWayToSource}" Content="{Binding Button2.Content}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="213,134,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <Button Content="MODEL" Command="{Binding VM.TargetButton.Push}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="273,86,-14,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

### mainWindow.xaml.cs

```
namespace button_binding
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public ObservableButton Button0 { get; set; }
        public ObservableButton Button1 { get; set; }
        public ObservableToggleButton Button2 { get; set; }

        public ViewModel VM { get; set; }

        public MainWindow ()
        {
            // finish off the view build
            //   These objects contain pure view state and UI behaviour
            //   no reference to model or view controls!

            Button0 = new ObservableButton(new List<string> { "Paused", "Logging" }, false);
            Button1 = new ObservableButton(new List<string> { "Paused", "Logging" }, false);
            Button2 = new ObservableToggleButton(new List<string> { "Log All", "Log VBA" }, false);

            InitializeComponent();

            // build the view model and connect it to the view

            VM = new ViewModel(button2);
            DataContext = VM;    //<-- this is what I want to do
//          DataContext = this;  //<-- this is what I have to do
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand your question. Why do you think this has anything to do with partial classes? The XAML you posted requires the `DataContext` to be `this` because it references properties in `MainWindow`. This has nothing to do with partial classes. You can set the `DataContext` to the `VM` value if you want, as long as you provide an alternative mechanism for the bindings to the `MainWindow` properties (e.g. name the `MainWindow` and use `ElementName` in the binding, or use `RelativeSource` in the binding with `AncestorType=Window`).

Comment: @PeterDuniho Ok, thanks. What's the syntax for the element binding? I tried dot and colon in the binding but no joy. Or, what's the canonical way to do the binding without setting the view stuff in the data context?

Comment: @PeterDuniho thanks, I figured it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As advised in comments...

### name the main window and use ElementName in the binding

```
<Window x:Class="button_binding.MainWindow"
        x:Name="View"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid Margin="0,0,183,134">
        <Button x:Name="button0" Command="{Binding ElementName=View, Path=Button0.DelegateClick}" Content="{Binding ElementName=View, Path=Button0.Content}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="112,82,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>
        <Button x:Name="button1" Command="{Binding ElementName=View, Path=Button1.DelegateClick}" Content="{Binding ElementName=View, Path=Button1.Content}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="112,134,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>
        <ToggleButton Name="button2" IsChecked="{Binding ElementName=View, Path=Button2.On, Mode=OneWayToSource}" Content="{Binding ElementName=View, Path=Button2.Content}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="213,134,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <Button Content="MODEL" Command="{Binding TargetButton.Push}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="273,86,-14,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

### Using RelativeSource FindAncestor

```
<Window x:Class="button_binding.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid Margin="0,0,183,134">
        <Button x:Name="button0" Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=Button0.DelegateClick}" Content="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=Button0.Content}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="112,82,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>
        <Button x:Name="button1" Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=Button1.DelegateClick}" Content="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=Button1.Content}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="112,134,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>
        <ToggleButton Name="button2" IsChecked="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=Button2.On, Mode=OneWayToSource}" Content="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=Button2.Content}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="213,134,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <Button Content="MODEL" Command="{Binding TargetButton.Push}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="273,86,-14,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

#### Or

```
<Window x:Class="button_binding.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <RelativeSource x:Key="View" Mode="FindAncestor" AncestorType="{x:Type Window}"></RelativeSource>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid Margin="0,0,183,134">
        <Button x:Name="button0" 
                Command="{Binding Button0.DelegateClick, RelativeSource={StaticResource View}}" 
                Content="{Binding Button0.Content, RelativeSource={StaticResource View}}" 
                HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="112,82,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>
        <Button x:Name="button1" Command="{Binding Button1.DelegateClick, RelativeSource={StaticResource View}}" 
                Content="{Binding Button1.Content, RelativeSource={StaticResource View}}" 
                HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="112,134,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>
        <ToggleButton Name="button2" IsChecked="{Binding Button2.On, RelativeSource={StaticResource View}, Mode=OneWayToSource}" 
                Content="{Binding Button2.Content, RelativeSource={StaticResource View}}" 
                HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="213,134,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <Button Content="MODEL" Command="{Binding TargetButton.Push}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                Margin="273,86,-14,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Then, in the code behind, can delete the VM object and just do...

```
        // build the view model and connect it to the view
        DataContext = new ViewModel(button2);
```